# Terraform objects and nested loops

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to transform a `map(object)`, but I feel like the Terraform documentation is a bit lacking when it comes to more complex use-cases for loops.

Is anyone able to write a for loop so that `output.solution` equals `local.desired_output`?

```
locals {
  
  users = {
    user1 = {
      teams = {
        team1 = "member"
        team2 = "admin"
      }
    }
    
    user2 = {
      teams = {
        team1 = "member"
      }
    }
  }
  
  desired_output = {
    user1_team1 = {
      user = "user1"
      team = "team1"
      role = "member"
    }
    
    user1_team2 = {
      user = "user1"
      team = "team2"
      role = "admin"
    }
    
    user2_team1 = {
      user = "user2"
      team = "team1"
      role = "member"
    }
  }
  
}

output "solution" {
  value = ???
}
```

EDIT:

Found a solution, but it's ugly:

```
locals {

  temp_output = flatten([
    for user, data in local.users : [
      for team, role in data.teams : {
        join("-", [user, team]) = {
          "user" = user
          "team" = team
          "role" = role
        }
      }
    ]
  ])

}

output "solution" {
  value = {
    for tuple in local.temp_output : keys(tuple)[0] => values(tuple)[0]
  }
}
```

Can anyone suggest a cleaner way to do this?

Edit 2:

Following up on Martin Atkins comment that cleanliness is subjective:
What I don't like about my solution is that it requires me to wrap my loops in various kinds of brackets, and then use another loop to unpack them. What I would like to do, is create my desired output directly from a nested loop, without the intermediate step where I create a list of tuples.

Something like this would be cleaner, if it worked:

```
# Does not work
output = {
  for user, data in local.users :
    for team, role in data.teams :
      join("-", [user, team]) => {
        "user" = user
        "team" = team
        "role" = role
      }
}
```

I don't fully understand why the above doesn't work; it seems like you can't do a nested loop unless the inner loop is contained within `[]` or `{}`, which then requires more code later on to unwrap in order to reach a `for_each` friendly object structure.

Comment: why not just `value = local.desired_output`?

Comment: `desired_output` just an example I created by hand to demonstrate what end result I want. should probably not have put it in the `locals` block, I can see why that's confusing. Sorry!

Comment: Without knowledge of what were building this output from this can't be answered?

Comment: What do you mean? The problem is to create a `map(object)` like `local.desired_output` by modifying `local.users`.


I've provided a solution, so the question can definitely be answered.

Comment: You should probably optimize the design of the original struct to be `map(map(string))` with `team(user(arg))`. It would be awkward for most use cases as it currently exists. You could also probably even invoke `zipmap` afterward for this use case.

Comment: It's hard to suggest what might be "a cleaner solution" because the idea of "cleanliness" is a subjective one. Perhaps you could edit your question to talk about what parts of your solution you consider "ugly" and what characteristics you'd consider "clean", which might then allow suggesting other features that better meet your subjective criteria.